# How to use a single value from foreach inside another foreach tag which is inside the same foreach

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, foreach, laravel-views

In my view page i have used the following loop:

```
@foreach ($type as $ingtype)    
   <h4>{{$ingtype->Ing_type}}</h4> 
       @foreach (${{$ingtype->Ing_type}} as $ing)
          <input type="checkbox" name="ing[]" value="{{$ing->ing_id}}" />
          <label for="{{$ing->Ing_name}}">{{$ing->Ing_name}}</label>
       @endforeach
@endforeach
```

What i'm trying to do here is that from

> {{$ingtype->Ing_type}}

i get values  Dairy, Vegetable, Meat and so on. So i need those values in the foreach inside it in

> @foreach (${{$ingtype->Ing_type}} as $ing)

which must mean

> ($Dairy as $ing)

then another loop gives

> ($Vegetable as $ing)

Comment: Please provide the data structure of $type

Answer (score 0):

You can directly use like this

```
@foreach ($type as $ingtype)    
   <h4>{{$ingtype->Ing_type}}</h4> 
   @foreach ($ingtype->Ing_type as $ing)
      <input type="checkbox" name="ing[]" value="{{$ing->ing_id}}" />
      <label for="{{$ing->Ing_name}}">{{$ing->Ing_name}}</label>
   @endforeach
@endforeach
```

Comment: i throws an error of invalid argument passed in foreach